# Locust- how to pass different host address

Tags: locust

We have two tasks under the same class, both are pointing to different hosts.

> Example:
> First task (Create a new token) pointing to host - HTTP://xyz.abc.new
> Second task (Create a new token-old) pointing to host-  HTTP://xyz.abc.old

```
import time
from locust import User, HttpUser, task, between, SequentialTaskSet

class LoginTaskSet(SequentialTaskSet):

@task
def generate_token(self):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    launch_response_new = self.client.post("/oauth2/access?grant_type=password&username=abcd@xyz.com&password=SWr5q3ghhhSd", headers=headers,name = "Create a new token")
    print("Launch - Response body: {}".format(launch_response_new.text))

@task
def generate_old_token(self):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    launch_response_old = self.client.post("/oauth/access?grant_type=password&username=abcd@xyz.com&password=SWr5q3ghhhSd", headers=headers,name = "Create a new token- old")
    print("Launch - Response body old: {}".format(launch_response_old.text))
   
class Login(HttpUser):
tasks = [LoginTaskSet]
wait_time = between(1, 2)
```

How to send host value's as part of each request ? How to run the locust without passing host value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it the full URL in your client calls. It should only use the `host` you give it when your endpoints start with `/`. So instead of just `"/oauth2/…"` you’d do `"http://xyz.abc.new/oauth2/..."`.